# Jira Custom field mediawiki internal links not working

Tags: jira, mediawiki, jira-plugin, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I have a custom field named as workaround in Jira. Whenever I put a mediawiki link into it with the alias it does work for ex:  [[Documentation:Product:Manual:TopicName|alias]] is the text in my workaround field. it should get converted to link but its not happening

Comment: Why would MediaWiki formatting work in some random place in some software that's not MediaWiki?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use a URL, not MediaWiki markup. As Tgr says, you shouldn't expect MediaWiki syntax to work in software that isn't MediaWiki. For how to make links in JIRA, take a look at the [the JIRA wiki docs](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=links).